# Load jar file locally

Tags: java

Let's say I have a jar file and I want users to load it locally from the Internet... to speed up the loading I say... how would I go about doing that?

Like when you access it from http://mydomain.com... the jar file is from my documents/game/test.jar

Comment: beware of Java Web Start: it *looks* good, but there are a *lot* of very serious gotchas using JWS.  One of them being that you won't be able to produce a portable Java application following the Apple guidelines.  In other words: your app will "scream" Java and OS X users positively, definitely and utterly **hate** that.  OS X apps should be packaged and served to OS X users the OS X way and should at least follow the Java Apple guidelines... That is my take on it: JWS is a big no-no if you want to produce a professional looking Java app working on OS X.

Comment: @NoozNooz42 - Your comment is tangential to the question asked, IMO.  I don't see any indication that @Dan is 1) developing specifically for OS X, or 2) concerned about producing a "professional looking" Java app on OS X.

Comment: So you want to write an Applet and then Lazy load some jar files and run code in there ? By Lazy Loading, I mean loading the jar file(s) only when and if you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the URLClassLoader class, I think it will do what you want.
Here is a good description: 
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/classloaders/

EDIT: Forget it, Unsigned Applets cannot create ClassLoaders.

For an Applet you will need to download everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the purpose of JNLP files (also called "Java Web Start"). Or I have misunderstood your problem...

You can find the official documentation on Oracle website : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html

An example famous application using this system : [SweetHome3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/index.jsp)

Comment: Yes.  More comprehensively, Java Web Start.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start

Comment: I have seen a applet called RuneScape do it where they cache some files in there....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but it sounds like you want Java Web Start.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html

You would create a jnlp file, and put a link to it on your website.  Java will take care of downloading the file and starting it.  The .jar file would be stored in a cache, and it shouldn't need to be redownloaded unless the cache is cleared or you replace your old .jar file with a new one.